# Alterar classe apos 3s via javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Preciso alterar a classe de alguns elementos após 3 segundos que começar a carregar o site, quero fazer isso mas não consigo, estava tentando com `SetTimeout`mas não consigo manipular a questão dos segundos e não encontrei solução via Google.
Quero que o site carrega com a div na classe `.oculto` e depois de 3 segundos ela passe para a classe `.visivel`
Alguém sabe de alguma solução, por favor?

Segue Exemplo:
HTML

```
<div class="oculto"></div>
```

CSS

```
.oculto{opacity:"0"}
.visivel{opacity:"1";width:100%;height:10%;background-color:#cccccc;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sintaxe para tal seria assim:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('.oculto').classList.add('visivel');
}, 3 * 1000);
```

Como o JavaScript trabalha em milisegundos tens de passar 3000 ms ao `setTimeout`. Repara que escrevi `setTimeout` com o primeiro "s" pequeno.

Se tiveres vários elementos podes fazer assim:

```
var ocultos = document.querySelectorAll('.oculto');
for (var i = 0; i < ocultos.length; i++){
    ocultos[i].classList.add('visivel');
}
```

Comment: Funcionou mas em apenas 1 elemento, apliquei em 1 div e 2 img e só na div esta funcionando, os outros item a classe ainda continua oculto.

Comment: Não funcionou em vários elementos, somente em um, a solução foi criar mais classes como oculto1 oculto2 oculto3 e criar tbm 3 `setTimeout` mudando para a classe visível, não sei se seria o correto, mas funcionou. Obrigado @sergio

Comment: @ClaytonFurlanetto usa a mesma classe para todos. Adicionei essa variante à resposta.

Comment: não deu certo esta fazendo o contrario em 3s esta sumindo todos os item com a classe `.oculto` Fiz dessa forma, esta correto? `setTimeout(function(){
 var ocultos = document.querySelectorAll('.oculto');
for (var i = 0; i < ocultos.length; i++){
    ocultos[i].classList.add('.visivel');
};
},4 * 1000);`

Comment: @ClaytonFurlanetto Exato. O código que coloquei era para colocar dentro do `setTimeout` como fizeste.

Comment: Realmente não deu certo, mas da outra forma funcionou, então vou deixar assim msm. vlw.

Answer (score 1):

tem a função chamada sleep(), onde você passa por parâmetro o tempo, em milissegundos

Comment: Qual é essa função `sleep()`?

Comment: É uma função de espera

Comment: Essa função é do php, não é?

Comment: Acho que a resposta no formato atual se adequaria mais como um comentário, seria interessante colocar exemplo de uso

Comment: @gabrielfalieri Pelo que pesquisei parece interessante essa função, mas não consegui aplicar no meu caso, estou iniciando em js ainda, vou testar as outras respostas, mas obrigado, essa função é muito interessante vou me aprofundar mais nela.

Comment: Acho que a setTimeOut ficaria mais fácil pra tu aplicar, iniciando

Comment: Tbm acho, estou testando a resposta do @sergio acredito que funcionará, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Bem simples:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]).classList.remove("oculto");
(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]).classList.add("visivel");


 },3000)
```

Como a contagem do setTimeout é em milissegundos são necessários 3.000 para 3 segundos

Comment: Nesse caso só funcionaria com div´s correto? Se fosse uma img, já não funcionaria.

Comment: Bom, aí eu usei um seletor básico, poderia pegar pelo id, classe, nome da tag, seria indiferente o importante é o elemento selecionado